# charles can't catch local desktop HTTP request on some computer

Tags: http, local, charles-proxy

I'm using charles on my computer to catch HTTP request from the desktop app(developed by me) on my computer to our server, and the charles works fine. 
However, on my team members computer, the charles failed to catch the request sent by the same desktop application. The certification and the settings are same, and we are in the same domain, so I quite confused what's the problem it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable proxying on localhost in Charles app.

- Charles for Windows: **Proxy > Windows Proxy**
- Charles for MacOS: **Proxy > MacOS Proxy**

[image]